# Get nearest previous sibling by tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have jQuery for hierarchical checkboxes that looks like this

My html:

```
<ul class='tristate'>
   <li>
      <input type='checkbox' />
      <label />
      <ul>
         <li>
            <input type='checkbox' />
            <label />
         </li>
         <li>
            <input type='checkbox' />
            <label />
            <ul>
               <li>
                   <!--can be more in the hierarchy -->
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".tristate", function (event) {
    var $source = $(event.target);
    var checked = $source.prop("checked");

    //filter checkboxes that are checked the opposite way to the source
    var selector = checked ? ':not(:checked)' : ':checked';

    //set all descendant checkboxes to the same value as the source
    $source
        .siblings("ul")
        .find('input:checkbox')
        .filter(selector)
        .prop({
            indeterminate: false,
            checked: checked
        });

    //parents are indeterminate if there are sibling checkboxes 
    //that are checked the opposite way to the source
    var $checkboxesNextToLabel = $lis.children('input:checkbox');
    var $checkboxesInsideLabel = $lis.children('label').children('input:checkbox');
    var indeterminate = $checkboxesNextToLabel
                        .add($checkboxesInsideLabel)
                        .filter(selector).length > 0;

    //set state of parent checkboxes
    $source
        .parentsUntil(".tristate")
        .filter('ul')
        .prev('label')  //label must always be first previous
        .prev('input:checkbox') //checkbox must always be second previous
        .prop({
            indeterminate: indeterminate,
            checked: checked && !indeterminate
        });
});
```

This does work with the mark-up I currently have in my application, but
I would like to make the code a little more robust when traversing to the parent checkbox. To be specific - `.filter('ul').prev('label').prev('input:checkbox')` means that the input must immediately precede the label and the label must immediately precede the input.

What I'd like to have is a command like `closest` that traverses siblings rather than ancestors so I could write something like `.filter('ul').prevNearest('input:checkbox')`

**EDIT - WARNING**
For anyone who comes across this question and wants to use the code in a checkbox hierarchy, beware. My logic is flawed. Grandparents have to check all their children. This code doesn't do that.

Comment: What about `$(this).parentsUntil(".tristate").filter('ul').prevAll('input:checkbox').first()`

Comment: Is `$(this).closest('.tristate').find('input:first')` what you're after?

Comment: @Taleeb - see my comment on Angela's answer

Comment: @j08691 No, I'm looking for all the "ancestor" checkboxes of a checkbox in a hierarchy, not just the top level one. But they aren't direct ancestors because the hierarchy is defined using lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try the following code to loop through all the ul elements and find the nearest checkbox..

```
var ulCol = $(this).parentsUntil(".tristate").filter('ul');
    ulCol.each(function(){
        $(this).prevAll('input:checkbox:first').prop({
            indeterminate: indeterminate,
            checked: checked && !indeterminate
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's [.prevAll()](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) returns all the previous elements (that optionally match a selector). It returns them in order, from the closest to the element to the farthest.

Since you only want the first match, you'll only need to select the first element found:

```
$source
    .parentsUntil(".tristate")
    .filter('ul')
    .prevAll('input:checkbox')[0]
```

You could also add a `.length > 0` condition to check whether any previous element matches your selector.

Comment: Thanks, I did not realise that the elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling. Unfortunately, the flaw with this is that there is a hierarchy of `ul` elements here, and we need to find the nearest previous sibling for all of them. Using `.first()` or `[0]` is only ever going to find one element.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize that. In that case I would iterate over the ul elements (with jquery's each, for example) and get the nearest previous for each of them. Sorry I can't explain better, I'm not at the computer right now.